# How to set Rank based on Score

Tags: sql

I have query like this

```
SELECT     CJ.JOURNAL_ID AS JOURNAL_ID, 
           VOLUME,
           ISSUE,
           PAPER_ID,
           COUNT(PAPER_ID) AS PAPER_COUNT
FROM       cafet_paper_details CPD 
INNER JOIN CAFET_JOURNAL       CJ  ON  CJ.JOURNAL_ID = CPD.JOURNAL_ID  
GROUP BY   JOURNAL_ID,VOLUME, ISSUE
ORDER BY   JOURNAL_ID,VOLUME
```

which gives me the following results

```
JOURNAL_ID  VOLUME  ISSUE   PAPER_ID  PAPER_COUNT  
----------  ------  ------  --------  -------------
        18  2008    04            33             18
        18  2009    05            46              3
        18  2012    03            10             22
        19  2016    1              9              1
```

From the above table I want to add a column 'VOLUME_RANK' based on ASC VOLUME (for volume 2008 i should get volume_rank as 1, for 2009 as 2, 2010 as 3 and so on)

expected output

```
JOURNAL_ID  VOLUME  ISSUE   PAPER_ID  PAPER_COUNT   VOLUME_RANK
----------  ------  ------  --------  ------------- ------------
        18  2008    04            33             18     1
        18  2009    05            46              3     2
        18  2012    03            10             22     5
        19  2016    1              9              1     9
```

Comment: which db you are using ?

Comment: I would guess `mysql` if that query runs.  If not, `paper_id` would have to be included in the `group by` clause...

Comment: Will it always be 2008 or is that year dynamic?  If so just use `Volume - 2007` If not, you could do the same just with selecting the `min` of `Volume` in a subquery...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CJ.JOURNAL_ID AS JOURNAL_ID,
   VOLUME,
   (VOLUME -2007) VOLUME_RANK ISSUE,
                              PAPER_ID,
                              COUNT(PAPER_ID) AS PAPER_COUNT
```

FROM cafet_paper_details CPD
INNER JOIN CAFET_JOURNAL CJ ON CJ.JOURNAL_ID = CPD.JOURNAL_ID
GROUP BY JOURNAL_ID,
         VOLUME,
         ISSUE
ORDER BY JOURNAL_ID,
         VOLUME

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you seem to want simple subtraction:

```
SELECT CJ.JOURNAL_ID, VOLUME, ISSUE, PAPER_ID,
       COUNT(PAPER_ID) AS PAPER_COUNT,
       (VOLUME - 2007) as VOLUME_RANK
FROM cafet_paper_details CPD INNER JOIN
     CAFET_JOURNAL CJ
     ON CJ.JOURNAL_ID = CPD.JOURNAL_ID  
GROUP BY JOURNAL_ID, VOLUME, ISSUE
ORDER BY JOURNAL_ID, VOLUME;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with view1 as 
(SELECT     CJ.JOURNAL_ID AS JOURNAL_ID, 
       VOLUME,
       ISSUE,
       PAPER_ID,
       COUNT(PAPER_ID) AS PAPER_COUNT
FROM       cafet_paper_details CPD 
INNER JOIN CAFET_JOURNAL       CJ  ON  CJ.JOURNAL_ID = CPD.JOURNAL_ID  
GROUP BY   JOURNAL_ID,VOLUME, ISSUE
ORDER BY   JOURNAL_ID,VOLUME
),
view2 as (
select JOURNAL_ID, VOLUME, ISSUE, PAPER_ID, PAPER_COUNT, (select min(volume)         from view1) from view1 MIN_VOLUME
)
select JOURNAL_ID, VOLUME, ISSUE, PAPER_ID, PAPER_COUNT, MIN_VOLUME, (VOLUME-MIN_VOLUME + 1) rank from view2
```